# Unable to get variable in Ansible Jinja template of a different / dynamic host

Tags: variables, ansible, runtime-error, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I have a variable `final_delegate` that determines the hosts depending upon user passed parameter  `-e perform_action=nslookup`

```
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

   - set_fact:
       final_delegate: "{{ 'localhost' if perform_action in 'telnetcurlnslookuptracerouteget_ip_address' else 'dest_nodes' }}"


- name: "Play 2"
  hosts: "{{ hostvars.localhost.final_delegate }}"
  tasks:

   - name: Run command
     ignore_errors: yes
     command:  ls -ltr /tmp/all.pdf
     register: cmdoutput

   - name: Creating body template
     template:
       src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/body.html.j2"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/body.html.tmp"
     delegate_to: localhost
```

Here is my `body.html.j2`

```
 <tr>
    <td>{{ inventory_hostname }}</td>
    <td><pre>{{ hostvars.[inventory_hostname].cmdoutput.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}</pre></td>
  </tr>
```

I get the below error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:   </tr>
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected name or number. String:  <tr>\n    <td>{{ inventory_hostname }}</td>\n    <td><pre>{{ hostvars.[inventory_hostname].cmdoutput.stdout_lines | join('\\n') }}</pre></td>\n    </tr>\n\n"}
```

I also tried the following:

```
1.
    <td><pre>{{ hostvars.[hostvars.localhost.final_delegate].cmdoutput.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}</pre></td>
2.
    <td><pre>{{ hostvars.['hostvars.localhost.final_delegate'].cmdoutput.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}</pre></td>
```

Maybe I'm not getting the syntax right. Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
hostvars.[inventory_hostname]
```

...is not valid Jinja syntax. When referencing a variable attribute, you have two options:

1. Dot notation: `item.attribute`
2. Bracket notation: `item["attribute"]`

When you want to reference an attribute whose name is contained in a variable, you need the second (bracket) syntax, so:

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname].cmdoutput.stdout_lines
```

---

If it helps, this runs without errors when I run it locally (whether or not `/tmp/all.pdf` exists):

```
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    perform_action: something
  tasks:
   - set_fact:
       final_delegate: "{{ 'localhost' if perform_action in 'telnetcurlnslookuptracerouteget_ip_address' else 'dest_nodes' }}"


- name: "Play 2"
  hosts: "{{ hostvars.localhost.final_delegate }}"
  tasks:

   - name: Run command
     ignore_errors: true
     command:  ls -ltr /tmp/all.pdf
     register: cmdoutput

   - name: Creating body template
     template:
       src: "body.html.j2"
       dest: "body.html.tmp"
     delegate_to: localhost
```

Using the fixed template:

```
 <tr>
    <td>{{ inventory_hostname }}</td>
    <td><pre>{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].cmdoutput.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}</pre></td>
  </tr>
```

Note that you don't need to use `hostvars` in the above template; you could write instead:

```
 <tr>
    <td>{{ inventory_hostname }}</td>
    <td><pre>{{ cmdoutput.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}</pre></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: i get the following error `
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Trying 192.168.27.96...\nConnected to USDFW11AS180V.\nEscape character is '^]'.\n\ntelnet> close\nConnection closed."
}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"}
`

Comment: That's a different problem: it's telling you that `cmdoutput` doesn't have a `stdout_lines` attribute, which could be true if the task was skipped, or it was a loop, etc. Using a `debug` task to print out the value of `hostvars[inventory_hostname].cmdoutput` will help figure out what's going on.